# Is it possible to create nested state inside nested state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to create multi step form based on angularui nested states.

I want to create a multi-step form inside nested state.

So my question is: is it possible to create nested state inside nested state?

Comment: A simple google search told me that it is possible - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views. Why didn't you do this before asking the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Example:

```
.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('root', {
            templateUrl: 'root.html',
            controller: 'rootCtrl'
        })
        .state('root.nested', {
            templateUrl: 'nest1.html',
            controller: 'nested1Ctrl'
        })
        .state('root.nested.nested', {
            templateUrl: 'nested2.html',
            controller: 'nested2Ctrl'
        });
});
```